# $wpdb delete statement not working properly

Tags: wordpress

I'm woking on a Wordpress project. I have been trying to delete repeater rows like the picture below,

[image]

My app's process is to delete the old data and replace with new data.

Rows I want to delete contain word **'pricing'**. So I have tried to use function below,

```
function delete_pricing($post_id)
{
    global $wpdb;

    try {
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM %s WHERE meta_key LIKE "%pricing%" AND post_id = %d';
        $query = $wpdb->prepare($sql, $wpdb->postmeta, $post_id);
        var_dump($query);
        echo '<br>';
        $result = $wpdb->query($query);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return 'Error! '. $wpdb->last_error .'<br>';
    }
}
```

But it is not working. As you can seen in the code, I have tried using **var_dump($query);** to watch the query statement. It displays like

> string(206) "DELETE FROM 'wp_postmeta' WHERE meta_key LIKE "{ed4207d3ae7fb5bb000695361c221562aa55fe8fea8216916f55e2eb6963ad7a}pricing{ed4207d3ae7fb5bb000695361c221562aa55fe8fea8216916f55e2eb6963ad7a}" AND post_id = 4013"

No rows are deleted.

Please help. I have no idea how to solve this.

ps. sorry for my poor English. I'm learning it.

> **EDIT**

I have tried several way, for example,

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "DELETE FROM %s WHERE meta_key LIKE %s AND post_id = %d;",
    $wpdb->postmeta,
    '%' . $wpdb->esc_like('pricing') . '%',
    $post_id
);

$query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "DELETE FROM %s WHERE meta_key LIKE '%%pricing%%' AND post_id = %d;",
    $wpdb->postmeta,
    $post_id
);

$query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "DELETE FROM %s WHERE meta_key LIKE '%%%pricing%%' AND post_id = %d;",
    $wpdb->postmeta,
    $post_id
);
```

But there is nothing works. But When I tried using direct query like

```
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '%pricing%' AND post_id =" . $post_id);
```

It works properly. Buy this way is too risky for SQL injection.

Comment: Please run the same query in the PHPMyAdmin, see if any rows are deleted on the PHPMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

`$wpdb->prepare()` is treating the `%pricing%` bit in your query as a fragment marker, hence the "weird" output you're seeing afterwards.

Try using the [esc_like()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/esc_like/) method instead:

```
$meta_key = 'pricing';
$query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "DELETE FROM %s WHERE meta_key LIKE %s AND post_id = %d;",
    $wpdb->postmeta,
    '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($meta_key) . '%',
    $post_id
);
```

Alternatively, assuming your meta key name won't change, this should also work:

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "DELETE FROM %s WHERE meta_key LIKE '%%pricing%%' AND post_id = %d;",
    $wpdb->postmeta,
    $post_id
);
```

Note the usage of `%%` here: it "escapes" the `%` symbol so the `prepare()` method doesn't use it as a fragment marker.